# Django from dynamic data insertion

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am basically making a django form using the models given below:

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)

class Device(models.Model):
    device_type         = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType,to_field='device_type')
    serial_number       = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    in_use_by           = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field='username')
    brand               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    model               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    type_number         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    mac_address         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)

class Repair(models.Model):
    device_type                     = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType,to_field='device_type')
    submitted_by                    = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field='username')
    comments                        = models.TextField()
    repair_request_date             = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    repair_status                   = models.ForeignKey(RepairStatus, to_field="repair_status", null=True)
    repair_cost_estimate            = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

My devicetype option contains the following values:

```
Dongle Charger
Desktop Power Cord
Laptop Charger
Dongle
Keyboard
Mouse
Desktop
Laptop
```

Now, suppose a particular user possesses only laptop and mouse. If he clicks for repair device option in my main form then, according to the models, the form will display all the values of the devicetype in the dropdown. What I want is, the dropdown must display only laptop and mouse i.e. only those devicetype that are associated with a particular user. How can i achieve this? Requesting help at the earliest.

Comment: What form do you use?

Comment: How do you store what a `User` owns?

Comment: I am using ModelForm. @Willem Van Onsem